# Solving a linear system of ODEs with repeated eigenvalues but distinct eigenvectors.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose I have a linear system of ODEs given by the system:

$$\dot{\vec{x}}= A\vec{x}$$ where $A$ is an $(n\times n)$ matrix and $\vec{x}$ is a $(n\times 1)$ column vector.

Now suppose that the matrix A has repeated **eigenvalues** but has $n$ distinct linearly independent **eigenvectors**. Is there a simple way to solve the system?

The link below (to wolfram alpha) shows a $(6\times 6)$ matrix where this is the case.
[See here for an example of a matrix where this happens](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7Ba,1,0,0,0,1%7D,%7B1,-a,1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,a,1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,-a,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,1,a,1%7D,%7B1,0,0,0,1,-a%7D%7D).

I know that if there are $n$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots , \lambda_n$, the general solution is given by $$\vec{x} = \big(c_1 v_1 e^{\lambda_1t}+\ldots+c_nv_ne^{\lambda_n t}\big)$$

where $v_i$ is the corresponding eigenvector for $\lambda_i$ and $c_i$ is a constant.

Also, I know what to do when there are **repeated** eigenvalues, with corresponding **repeated** eigenvectors.

Is there an a similar way to solve the system with repeated eigenvalues but distinct eigenvectors?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are $n$ eigenvectors, then the matrix is diagonalizable and your formula for distinct eigenvalues also applies to this case.

When transforming a scalar linear equation with constant coefficients into a first order systems, this case, separate Jordan blocks for the same eigenvalue, never happens. As these are the typical text book examples for repeated eigenvalues, this perhaps originates your hesitation.

Comment: So I can just go ahead and write the solution as $$\vec{x} = c_1v_1e^{\lambda_1 t} + c_2v_2e^{\lambda_1 t} + \cdots +c_{n-1} v_{n-1}e^{\lambda_n t} + c_nv_ne^{\lambda _n t}?$$

Comment: @Daniel: This gives you an enumeration problem as that implies more than $n$ terms. But yes, you can write $$x⃗=v_1e^{λ_1t}+v_2e^{λ_2t}+⋯+v_me^{λ_mt}$$ with $m\le n$ and $v_k$ any vector in the eigenspace of $λ_k$.

Comment: Thanks. So we can just ignore the extra eigenvector for each eigenvalue?

Comment: The Jordan decomposition is a block-diagonal normal form of a matrix. The diagonal blocks with their special structure, corresponding to irreducible invariant subspaces, are the Jordan blocks.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate more on why we can ignore the extra eigenvector?

Comment: The "extra" eigenvectors are all contained in the eigen-space, $\ker(A-λ_kI)$. The dimension of that equals the degrees of freedom associated to that eigenvalue.

Comment: But then wouldn't choosing the positive or negative eigenvalues in the solution give rise to different results? For example, the eigenvalues in the example I gave come in pairs $\pm \lambda$. So if we choose $\lambda$ then this will give a different answer to $-\lambda$? Or will the associated eigenvectors take care of it?

Comment: ??? The assumption is that there are exactly $m$ distinct eigenvalues, and all have equality of algebraic and geometric multiplicity. And what about the complex eigenvalues?

Comment: Nevermind... I get it.

Comment: Yes, $+λ$ and $-λ$ are different eigenvalues. That both are eigenvalues is either an accident or has a strong structural reason, such as, as a very specific example, the matrix being the block matrix at the base of the Golub-Kahan SVD algorithm,...